# Mysql transaction question

Tags: mysql, transactions

My code:

```
mysql_query("SET AUTOCOMMIT=0");
mysql_query("START TRANSACTION");

insert_query, update_query1, update_query2

mysql_query("COMMIT");
update_query3
```

Why does `update_query3` query doesn't work if I put it after `COMMIT`? It works if I put it before the `COMMIT`. Why is that? It's really strange.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `COMMIT` (or `ROLLBACK` for that matter) marks the end of the transaction.

You'd have to use:

```
mysql_query("COMMIT AND CHAIN");
```

..to [create a new transaction to begin as soon as the current one ends, and the new transaction has the same isolation level as the just-terminated transaction](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html).

But it still means you need to have:

```
mysql_query("COMMIT");
```

...*after* the `update_query3` to commit the changes.

Answer (score 2):

First you disable auto-commit. Then you begin transaction, make changes and commit them. Then you execute another query that implicitly starts another transaction. In order for changes to get committed, you have to call "COMMIT" explicitly because auto-commit is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

update_query3 isn't part of any existing transaction. So it starts a new (implicit) transaction.

You never commit the transaction started by update_query3, so it'll get rolled back when you close the connection.

Comment: Because autocommit was disabled, there are no implicit transactions.

Comment: Well, it looks like mysql starts a new transaction for you if you don't issue `begin` yourself, with autocommit=0;

Comment: BEGIN and START TRANSACTION are interchangeable; I wonder if the issue is really that the tables are MyISAM (which doesn't support transactions anyway).